# Testing a transition between two activities and going back to the first activity

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, transition

I am developing an app that requires the user to press a button and it goes to another activity. The problem is that I cannot continue from there. I want to be able to simulate a button press and go back to the previous activity it was on. Here is my code.

```
package com.example.guy.smsclassproject;

import android.os.Looper;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.UiThreadTest;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ksl130230 on 11/5/2015.
 */
public class DraftsActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<DraftsActivity> {

    private DraftsActivity tester;
    private EditText searchText;
    private Button searchButton;
    private DraftsDatabase draftsDatabase;
    private MessageObject messageObject1;
    private MessageObject messageObject2;
    private MessageObject messageObject3;
    Button[] draftButtons;

    ArrayList<MessageObject> messagesToBeDisplayed;

    public DraftsActivityTest() {
        super(DraftsActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    @UiThreadTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
        {
            Looper.prepare();
        }
        draftsDatabase = new DraftsDatabase();
        draftsDatabase.clearData();
        messageObject1 = new MessageObject("hi", "5554",null, true);
        messageObject2 = new MessageObject("hi hi", "5555554",null, true);
        messageObject3 = new MessageObject("sup", "5435555554",null, true);
        draftsDatabase.addMessage(messageObject1);
        draftsDatabase.addMessage(messageObject2);
        draftsDatabase.addMessage(messageObject3);
        tester = getActivity();
        messagesToBeDisplayed = tester.messagesToBeDisplayed;
        searchText = (EditText) tester.findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        searchButton = (Button) tester.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);


    }


    @SmallTest
    @UiThreadTest
    public void testSearch() {
        searchText.setText("hij");
        searchButton.performClick();

        messagesToBeDisplayed = tester.messagesToBeDisplayed;
        assertEquals("Messages with the word hi", 0, messagesToBeDisplayed.size());

        searchText.setText("sup");
        searchButton.performClick();

        messagesToBeDisplayed = tester.messagesToBeDisplayed;
        assertEquals("Messages with the word sup", 1, messagesToBeDisplayed.size());

        searchText.setText("yo");
        searchButton.performClick();

        messagesToBeDisplayed = tester.messagesToBeDisplayed;
        assertEquals("Messages with the word yo", 0, messagesToBeDisplayed.size());

        searchText.setText("i");
        searchButton.performClick();

        messagesToBeDisplayed = tester.messagesToBeDisplayed;
        assertEquals("Messages with the word i", 2, messagesToBeDisplayed.size());

    }

    @SmallTest
    @UiThreadTest
    public void testRedisplay()
    {
        assertNotNull(tester.draftButtons[0]);
        tester.draftButtons[0].performClick();
        messagesToBeDisplayed = tester.messagesToBeDisplayed;
        assertEquals("Size of the list after deletion is 2", 2, messagesToBeDisplayed.size()); //presses the first button, which deletes it from the drafts
        getActivity();
        String buttonText0 = tester.draftButtons[0].getText().toString();
        if(buttonText0.equals("5555554: hi hi")) assertSame("Text redisplayed on the first button", buttonText0, messageObject2.toString()); //gets the text of the current button, since the messageobject1 was in draftsButtons0 before, not it should have messageobject2

        assertNotNull(tester.draftButtons[1]);
        String buttonText1 = tester.draftButtons[1].getText().toString();
        if(buttonText1.equals("5435555554: sup"))
            assertSame("Text redisplayed on the second button", buttonText1, messageObject3.toString());

    }

    @SmallTest
    @UiThreadTest
    public void testMessageButtons()
    {

        assertNotNull(tester.draftButtons[0]);
        tester.draftButtons[0].performClick();

        //THE PROBLEM IS LOCATED HERE.
        //As soon as I press the button, the app goes to another activity.
        //I want it to go back from the activity.

        assertNotNull(tester.draftButtons[1]);
        tester.draftButtons[1].performClick();

        messagesToBeDisplayed = tester.messagesToBeDisplayed;
        assertEquals("The draftsDatabase now only contains 1 message", 1, messagesToBeDisplayed.size());

        assertNotNull(tester.draftButtons[0]);
        tester.draftButtons[0].performClick();

        assertNull(draftsDatabase); //after you press all the buttons, the draftsDatabase should be empty because all the messages have been deleted

    }



}
```

Comment: You cannot continue from here? What is the issue exactly you are facing? Be more specific

Answer (score 0):

This is my code of application which I recently made. If user press a button it goes to another activity from this you will be to simulate a button press and go back to the previous activity and I also have made some modification that you can pass data from text view to second activity

MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);

        final EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
        String mesg = inputText.getText().toString();
        i.putExtra("mm",mesg );

        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Main2Activity

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.Transition;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewGroup RLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(data == null){
            return;
        }

        String mm = data.getString("mm");

        final TextView textVieww = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textVieww);
        textVieww.setText(mm);

        RLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.RLayout);

        RLayout.setOnTouchListener(
                new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener(){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        moveButton();
                        return true;
                    }
        });

    }

    public void onClickk(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.user.razaali.third" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#53ff00">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="First Screen"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/inputText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:width="250dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.razaali.third.Main2Activity"
    android:background="#fff306"
    android:id="@+id/RLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Secound Screen"
        android:id="@+id/textVieww"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClickk" />
</RelativeLayout>
```